# jquery plugin smartmenus-1.2.1 and jQuery-News-Ticker-master plugins crash

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-plugins

plugins jquery smartmenu clashes with plugins jquery news striker. Can anyone provide a solution to this problem. i just started learning

```
script src="{{ url('public/assets/js/jquery.smartmenus.js') }}"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url('public/assets/js/site.js') }}"></script>  
<script src="{{ url('public/assets/js/jquery.ticker.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: clashes how exactly? What specifically is the problem? Do you get an error? P.S. Why are you using such an ancient version of jQuery?

Comment: thank's ...now it work fine after using new jquery....